# Can anyone please identify this 6 pin SMD integrated circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

Can anyone please identify this 6 pin SMD integrated circuit or what it does? I could not find it by the code written on it.

It is from a solar charger and I need to replace it.

[image: photo of unknown device]

Comment: +1 .... very good picture .... please add a picture that shows a wider area of the board

Comment: If you don't know what it is, how do you know you need to replace it?

Comment: did you check polarity? it could be a littlefuse fast diode... try smaj6

Answer (score 8):

It is "AP5100" [Datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP5100.pdf). Which is Step down converter from Diodes Incorporated.

[image]